# How to open my installed app by link with using anchor tag like shown in below image

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Requirement is that i have created deeplink with scheme https and i want to open app when click on link and should always open app if installed otherwise open play store and like happen in payment app like phonepe when user click link from inbox then it will open link in browser and then browser automatically open app if installed[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lkRy.png)

Comment: You have to register `intent filter` in your activity to achieve this

Comment: you can use PackageManager to check if the app installed, then you can choose to open it or go to play store

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `intent-filter` like below in your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, another answer here may help when the app is installed, but won't help you when it is not installed. You may need to follow a different approach.

The solution you need is called deferred deep linking. 
Use [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) for this. You can use [Android Google Play referrer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) But I feel that's unreliable. As I've tried both of these methods, I prefer using Branch.io

At first, setting up Branch.io SDK feels tedious and complicated, but it definitely serves the purpose.

To get started you can follow [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/deep-linking-in-android-part-2-23e942293032) blog. This is a little old, but if you compare it with the latest Branch.io dashboard I'm sure it will help.

Moreover, if you still feel stuck at any point comment down here, I'll be happy to help as I've invested more time myself implementing deferred deep linking.